# Why does randomForest ordering of predictors matter in OOB error rate?

Tags: r, random-forest, modeling

I'm just looking for a general understanding of why the order of predictors in a randomForest can affect the OOB estimate. I think I might know the answer, but am not sure. I'm guessing it has to do with the way the trees are built (starting at the first predictor and branching out based on the second and so on. 
For example, in the titanic data set, i created the following randomForests:

```
rf.train.9 <- titanic.full[1:891, c("Pclass", "Age", "Fare", "FamSize", "Sex")]
rf.label <- as.factor(train$Survived)

set.seed(1234)
rf.9 <- randomForest(x = rf.train.9, y = rf.label, importance = TRUE, ntree = 1000)
rf.9
```

and

```
rf.train.9 <- titanic.full[1:891, c( "Age", "Fare", "FamSize", "Sex", "Pclass")]
rf.label <- as.factor(train$Survived)

set.seed(1234)
rf.9 <- randomForest(x = rf.train.9, y = rf.label, importance = TRUE, ntree = 1000)
rf.9
```

The only change here is moving Pclass from first to last predictor in the model. The first run computed a better OOB (15.6 % vs 15.82)

If my understanding as to the process the rf used is correct, it creates a more important question:

Is there a common practice for testing order of rf predictors? Or is it more of an artistic endeavor?

Thanks much.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your code, since `Pclass` appears first in both examples.

Comment: My bad. Thanks, it's fixed now.